# Copy ChartArea dimensions from one chart to another in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing code that copies the formatting from a selected table to a second selected table.  I'm having trouble copying the ChartArea dimensions like so:

I get an error 445 'Object doesn't support this action'

The code for this is:

```
sub copychartarea()
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart.ChartArea.Top = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Chart.ChartArea.Top
end sub
```

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ChartArea property of the Chart object is read-only, as per the following article...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.chartarea

Try the following instead...

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Top
```

Comment: I just noticed that if I use plotarea.top plotarea.left, i'm not getting the precise same placement on copying a chart to another.  Any ideas on how to do it exaxtly?

Comment: The Top position can be adjusted as long as the Bottom position doesn't extend beyond the ChartArea.  So, in other words, the PlotArea is constrained within the ChartArea.